# JAX-RS server authentication in embedded TJWS

Tags: authentication, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I have an embedded JBoss RESTEasy TJWS server that's serving `MyResourceService` class just fine:

```
TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer tjws = new TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer();
tjws.getDeployment().setApplicationClass(MyApplication.class.getName());
tjws.setPort(080);
tjws.getDeployment().setSecurityEnabled(true);
final SimpleSecurityDomain securityDomain = new SimpleSecurityDomain();
securityDomain.addUser("super", "pass", new String[] { "admin" });
tjws.setSecurityDomain(securityDomain);
tjws.start();
tjws.getDeployment().getRegistry().addPerRequestResource(MyResourceService.class, "base");
```

Unfortunately, even though I set up a user `super` with password `pass` in role `admin`, and even though I turn on security, from a browser I can use GET on the page mapped to `MyResourceService` with no problem, as if I had no users defined or any security turned on.

So I added the `@RolesAllowed({ "admin" })` annotation to the `MyResourceService` class and tried to navigate to the resource in my browser. Unfortunately, instead of getting a `401 Unauthorized` with a `WWW-Authenticate` header (which would trigger a browser dialog asking for username and password), the server sends back a `403 Forbidden`, which results in the request failing altogether.

How can I get the normal HTTP authentication handshaking to work with embedded TJWS with JAX-RS?